# Is google analytics ecommerce tracking safe?

Tags: javascript, security, google-analytics, e-commerce, csrf

With google analytics you can track ecommerce events,

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingEcommerce.html

I was wondering if this is a safe and dependable way of keeping track of these transactions.

The problem I see with this is that an attacker can add new events, so if this is your way of storing financial transactions, they can be changed by anyone seeing your javascript code.

Here is the scenario in which this code can be abused.

You have a client named Client C, he goes to the website and buys product P, then you store the transaction using this tool. Then an attacker goes to your website and modifies your javascript and tracks 10 other purchases, this way your data shows that Client C has bought 10 Ps, and when you invoice client C, he will be mad at you.

This way an attacker can basically attack your clients, and damage your reputation.

Am I wrong in saying this? Is there a way you could fix this? It seems to me tracking anything with Javascript can be prone to these kind of attacks, or there could be any ways of making them secure or not. I don't know if they can be called a request forgery attack or not. What do you think?

Comment: It seems very unusual to do *billing* based on data from the tracking tool. Should the actual E-Commerce system not be doing that? But to answer your question, I think you're right - there is no safe way to do this through JavaScript. Plus, I could simply turn off Javascript to not be billed at all.

Comment: Does analytics just not track if js in disabled? I thought there was something about images that Google used in this event?

Comment: Alex, it will probably still keep track of visits, but not these ecommerce events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woah! I would never use analytics as an aid to invoicing a client for the exact reasons you've just stated! It's great if you want to keep an eye on transactions and maybe do some reporting on those transactions, but the data should never been taking 100% literally because there are plenty of reasons why some transactions might not track, and others might be slightly wrong/duplicated. You should have a system in place that stores transactions and builds invoices from that stored securely on a server.

Comment: It seems like we agree, what google has made can not be depended upon, it's only to give you an idea, and it will give you a false idea if someone tries to mess with you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, it sounds like your worried someone will modify the code others see which isn't possible. A person can't modify the JavaScript your server **sends** to everyone. He can only modify the JavaScript your server *sent* to him.

However, that aside. Using JavaScript to do anything that should be done server side (like track/record purchases) is a bad idea. JavaScript is only for watching things you don't care if they are changed by the user.

Comment: I didn't mean actually modifying the javascript file on the server so it changes for everyone, an attacker can always modify your javascript file his browser, and send modified data to google analytics in their browser, and google analytics has no way of knowing whether this is actually data coming from your javascript file or a modified one.